# Do multiple instances of paying extra mana to target a permanent stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When I have two copies of [Diffusion Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDiffusion%20Sliver%5d) on the battlefield, does my opponent have to pay four mana, or two mana to target my slivers?
I mean it says, pay two, so when he pays two both cards should be happy, or does this stack?

An explanation how and why would be nice.

Comment: Related: [Do multiple instances of Arcbond stack?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/30249/6692)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For convenience, I will quote [Diffusion Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDiffusion%20Sliver%5d)'s ability:

> Whenever a Sliver creature you control becomes the target of a spell or ability an opponent controls, counter that spell or ability unless its controller pays {2}.

So, you've got two Diffusion Slivers. Let's call them Artemis and Boromir. Each of them has their own independent copy of this ability. When your opponent casts a spell that targets one of your slivers, you get *two* triggered abilities going on the stack: one from Artemis and one from Boromir.

When Artemis's triggered ability resolves, your opponent has to pay 2 mana to satisfy the cost of that ability (unless they let their spell be countered, but let's assume that doesn't happen). It's a general rule in Magic that **you cannot pay for more than one cost using the same resources**. So the two mana used to pay for Artemis's ability's cost cannot *also* pay for the cost of Boromir's ability. When they pay the mana, they no longer have that mana - just like money.

Later on when Boromir's triggered ability resolves, your opponent will have to find two additional mana to pay for that cost. That makes a total of four.

Comment: I _might_ not have posted this answer only because I couldn't resist giving the slivers funny names.

Comment: @G.Kner Well, thanks. For what it's worth, I usually find it useful to wait a while - maybe a day or so - before accepting an answer, so that you can really choose the best one. You don't _have_ to wait, of course, it's just something I've found useful in the past.

Answer (score 1):

They have to pay four mana, when he casts the spell both slivers trigger and their ability to counter the spell unless he pays mana goes on the stack, to prevent these ability's from countering his spell they need to pay two mana for each of them making him pay a total of four mana

Comment: Is there a case where you pay the cost, like in this case, can you call it a cost?, for one of multiple triggered abilities, where the others are paid too?

Comment: Just to be sure, i always look at one spell after another on the stack, there is nothing that can influence the next spell with my actions from the previous? Except stuff like making the target invalid, or countering it?

Comment: This only happens when something triggers twice but the ability states it can only happen once a turn

Answer (score 0):

Those are perfectly normal triggered abilities. Each ability triggers when a sliver is targeted with a spell or ability. The controller of the abilities gets to put them on the stack in any order he or she prefers and his opponent gets to choose to pay either 0, 2 or 4 colourless mana.

The fact that two cards have the same name does not change how triggered abilities work, or how they are put on the stack.